# Two or more machines on same Windows network with same client hostname

Tags: windows, networking, hostname

I unofficially manage a small (<10 machines) office network, with machines running on a variety of Windows operating systems:

- One on XP (This is running specialist software and hardware which is not compatible with newer Windows versions, so I can't easily update it).
- Several on Win7.
- A software-license and file server (very light usage) on Win Server 2008
- One on Windows 10 - Just been delivered, I haven't actually hooked it all up yet.

We've just discovered (by accident) a benefit to sharing the same hostname between two computers on the system, to do with the shonky way some old software is set up. Ultimately though the reasons why we want to do this can be considered irrelevant for the purposes of this question.

As far as I know the only machine which I've ever set up to be referred to by hostname is the server, which is accessed by it's hostname "[CompanyName]-Server", and none of the other machines on the network directly communicate with each other. I'm also not planning to duplicate the server's hostname, just some of the clients.

I don't believe I've ever set up any kind of Domain, Homegroup or Workgroup through Windows, I just set the server up with a static local IP Address (x.x.x.1) through the server's IP configuration settings within Windows, did the same with our network printers via their own configs, then set up our router as a DHCP server (x.x.x.100-199) for the other machines on the network.

All machines also share an internet connection through the router, but we are not hosting anything (websites, servers) etc. to anything outside of our LAN aside from VERY occasional TeamViewer (remote desktop) use.

I'm currently under the assumption that for the most part the hostname is just a "user-friendly" way of identifying machines on the network whereas most important functions will default to using the IP address.

What I need to know is if two (or more) machines with the same hostname, on the same network are likely to cause any general issues.

Just to clarify, when I use the term "hostname" I am talking about the "computer name" which is returned when I type "hostname" into a windows command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be (a little) pedantic the hostname is not the same as the computer name but usually is. You can have duplicate hostname's no problem (there is more than one host named www.google.com for instance).

First you are really probably talking about the machine name (the companyname-server in \companyname-server\files). Windows will assume this is unique. Second this is really the "machinename" - usually but not always the same as the hostname (thanks Microsoft).

Finally - if the server's name is unique and you are only using a Workgroup you *should* be OK - but don't be surprised to see some weirdness and this assumes the printers are all off the server or stand alone. Anything people want to go to needs to be unique, and if you ever go to a Windows Active Directory Domain you *must* have unique names*

*Ok, there are some tricks like DisableStictNameChecking and OptionalNames. Don't go there.

Comment: Yes, the machine name is what I'm talking about. The printers are standalone and only referred to by IP address, and the server is the only machine which any other computer accesses - there are no other machines acting as any kind of server and no shared directories or file sharing etc. Like I say I haven't specifically set up a workgroup or domain etc. and I'm not fully clear on what the difference is.

Comment: When in doubt use the IP and you'll be (almost) golden. Sometimes Windows will try too hard to make it easy but from what you've written you should be fine. A domain is where all the users & computers log into a domain controller server - does not sound like that's what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

I found the TheFiddlerWins' answer a bit too technical. And since he is talking about a Windows environment, I'll add my two cents.

> I'm currently under the assumption that for the most part the hostname is just a "user-friendly" way of identifying machines on the network whereas most important functions will default to using the IP address.

This is not entirely correct. It's certainly easier to tell your colleague to connect to "fileserver01" than to "192.168.241.11" or even "fe80::aa8f:5478:bca9:fe21". But with the introduction of IPv6, even in small networks, you will probably rely on automatically assigned IP addresses. Especially since you don't need DHCP servers anymore. (Personally, I would never ever again manually assign an IP address to a desktop computer. Be it IPv4 or IPv6.)

In that light, this is what's wrong with your statement: You won't be able to effectively address computers anymore, because IP addresses change. Unless of course you identify them by hostname.

Now, in an Active-Directory environment, the hostname must be unique.

In a Windows *WORKGROUP* environment, you may give all computers the same hostname (but they may complain).

But if you have to address a computer by name, e.g. because the software requires it, then there is no telling which computer actually receives a packet. It's even possible that one packet goes to *companyname-client* (192.168.0.1) and the next to *companyname-client* (192.168.0.2). That could cause simple problems like long transmission times, timeouts, disconnects up to serious security problems.

> We've just discovered (by accident) a benefit to sharing the same hostname between two computers on the system

I can only guess, but it sounds like you may have achieved some kind of higher availability of one of your applications or services. Going down that road, it is actually very common to have multiple servers behind a common hostname, to achieve redundancy. **But** this scenario is not as simple as giving two machines with identical hard- and software- and application-configuration the same hostname.

In summary. You might not experience problems at all. But you could run into trouble with certain software and even cause serious security holes. It totally depends on your environment.